# Why does styleurls use square backets while templateurl does does not?

Tags: angular, components

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-heroes',
 templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
```

My question is about why it uses square brackets while others do not?

Comment: Please avoid asking questions that can be answered by reading [the documentation.](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#styleUrls)

Comment: I read the documentation but it didn't make it clear that it was an array. I understand now thanks to the people that replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shehroz Khan,

As per angular component option name

**styleUrls** is plural and one or more URLs for files containing CSS stylesheets to use in this component.

**templateUrl** is singular for each component we can add only one component.html file so

**styleUrls** type is array and **templateUrl** is normal string.

Let me know if you have any further discussion on this

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have **`multiple templates`** for **`single`** component, but you can have **`different styles`** configured for simpile component.

That's why you have **`styleUrls`** as array.